# "Мясная тарелка" как вид еды

Tags: грамотная-речь

Знакомой нужно было по работе составить меню. В частности, там была такая фраза: "Обед включает в себя мясную тарелку, суп (по выбору), второе с гарниром, сдобу и напиток". Так вот, сложность вызвало употребление тут термина "мясная тарелка". С одной стороны, это вроде как название блюда, а с другой, получается, что на обед у человека тарелка.
Можно ли тут употребить термин "мясная тарелка"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Слово "тарелка" действительно сейчас приобрело новое значение вида кушания. Мясная, сырная, рыбная тарелка - практически в каждом заведении есть такое блюдо. Да и само слово "блюдо" означает посуду, тарелку.

Так что, по моему мнению, вполне уместно употреблять такое название прямо, без кавычек. Только желательно всё-таки расшифровать, что входит в его состав. Это можно сделать в скобках или сноской.

Если же остаются сомнения, слово "тарелка" можно заменить на "ассорти".

Comment: Мясная  тарелка  по  отношению  к  мясному  блюду - неологизм  или  профессиональный  сленг.  Имеет  право  на  существование,  если  обозначает  особый  вид  сервировки.

Answer (score 2):

Термин *мясная тарелка* обозначает  красиво сервированную мясную нарезку на праздничном или ресторанном столе. Кроме мяса там может присутствовать зелень и др. продукты. Самое главное, на мой взгляд, в *мясной тарелке* - это большое количество маленьких порций. Надо полагать, все-все-все форумчане не понаслышке знакомы с обсуждаемым предметом! Иногда сабж доедают на следующий день после пиршества...